# how to write a nested for loop using lodash?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, feathersjs

```
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] ;
arr2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

and I expact

```
// run time
    query() {
      stuff1 = a;
      stuff2 = 1;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = a;
      stuff2 = 2;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = a;
      stuff2 = 3;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = a;
      stuff2 = 4;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = b;
      stuff2 = 1;
    }
     query() {
      stuff1 = b;
      stuff2 = 2;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = b;
      stuff2 = 3;
    }
    query() {
      stuff1 = b;
      stuff2 = 4;
    }
    ...
    query() {
      stuff1 = c;
      stuff2 = 6;
    }
```

how to write code?

```
_.map(arr1, (res) => { reutrn _.map(arr2, (res2, res1) => ... } blabla
```

I have no ideas...

if i use zipWith, a:1 b:2 c:3 ... but i don't want it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = _.chain(arr1).map((item) => {
    return _.map(arr2, (item2) => {
       return {
          stuff1: item,
          stuff2: item2
       }
    })
}).flatten().value();
```

Output:

https://jsfiddle.net/htreL1of/3/